# Modifying 404.Liquid in Shopify

Tags: php, shopify

I am having a problem modifying HTML in 404.liquid.

Here is the JSON that I am trying to send: http://cl.ly/image/3r0l3w2q2E0S

This is my response:

```
array(1) { ["error"]=> string(157) "lexical error: invalid string in json text. ODE: START -->n
```

I think it is failed because of the HTML breaking the JSON. Is there some sort of encoding that Shopify is expecting in order to prevent such errors with the JSON?

Please advice. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure that error is coming from Shopify and not the library you’re using?

Comment: Also: could you please put your sample JSON in something like http://gist.github.com so it can be easily copy/pasted/used to try to reproduce the error?

Comment: The error is a direct response from the API call. I am using the Colin's API adapter (https://github.com/cmcdonaldca/ohShopify.php)

Comment: Here is the gist for the JSON: https://gist.github.com/3976467

Comment: Here is the PHP code I am running to get the error https://gist.github.com/3976510

Comment: Upon doing a view source on the error I get: 
    array(1) {
      ["error"]=>
      string(155) "lexical error: invalid char in json text.
              04.liquid","value":"<div id="col-main"     class="content">n

Comment: Try escaping your semi-colon? \:

Comment: @csaunders it actually dies before the semicolon :-(

Comment: I think I know why this is happening. It is because of the double quotes in the HTML, which messes with the JSON. Example: {"asset":{"key":"templates/404.liquid","value":"<div id="col-main" class="content">n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been fixed. It was due to the stripslashes() function in the PHP adapter. Here is the fix details:

https://github.com/nyalex/shopify_api/commit/029d5025b2d5acfa376d2160cbd9845189d9a06d